# Is it possible to select multiple bars on bar chart in d3.js with mouse

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bar-chart, brush

I was trying to google for this, but no luck.

What i want is to take standard bar chart in d3.js, for example like this

http://bl.ocks.org/1218567

and select with my mouse middle 4 bars, and somehow get value of selected values only.

Is such thing possible with d3?

---

EDIT:
I think my question might be bit misleading, I don't want to do multiple clicks to select objects, i want to click and drag once and select underlying objects, see sencha example in my comment.

SOLVED:

d3.brush is the answer, you can see the working demo here
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/splom.html

Comment: I found semi-related example http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/view/data-view.html  

I would like same behavior, click and drag to select some items, and then in some callback i get selected objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this using the `.on()` function and the `click` event. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on). To be able to select multiple bars, you would need to keep track of the current selection in a global variable, for example an array that is added to and removed from as you click on unselected/selected bars. The code might look something like

```
var selection = [];
...
var bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    ...
    .on("click", function(d) {
        if(selection.indexOf(d) == -1) { selection.push(d); }
        else { selection.splice(selection.indexOf(d), 1); }
        updateSelectionDisplay();
    });
```

Comment: You could also toggle a `selected` bit on the data. For example, `bars.on("click", function(d) { d.selected = !d.selected; redraw(); })`.

Comment: Ok, is almost end of work time here (CET), but i promise to try it later today or tomorrow, will let you know of my result. I really appreciate the answer Lars!

Comment: One more thing, as you can see in example that i added to my question, I would like to select elements in ONE drag, not in multiple clicks.

My requirement is to present user with a bar chart, and give them ability to select range of bars and show values they selected, clicking on ~80 out of 100 bars is out of the question from the UX/business perspective.

Comment: You probably want to use [d3.svg.brush](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush) for this, although you could probably achieve it with "normal" event listeners as well.

Comment: @Mr.White No, but there's a `touch` event for that.